# Submittng Issue EnvioDTE to SII using c#

Tags: c#, webrequest

I'm making a bundle of submit Envio DTE to SII in Chile using C#.

Now I'm getting an html response, and get a this

**"HA OCURRIDO UN ERROR EN EL UPLOAD DEL ARCHIVO DE DOCUMENTOS TRIBUTARIOS ELECTRONICOS."**

I think the parameter is not deliveried correctly. The parameter Name is correctly on a their documentation. This Request should be emulate web broswer.

I really appreciate if anybody can help me.
**Code:**

```
       public string SendEnvioDte(string fileName, string token, Documento documento, string userRut)
       {
            string boundary = "----------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
            
            NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
            var url = "https://maullin.sii.cl/cgi_dte/UPL/DTEUpload";
            var RutEmisor = documento.Encabezado.Emisor.RUTEmisor;
            var RutReceptor = documento.Encabezado.Receptor.RUTRecep;
            var rutSender = userRut.Substring(0, 8);
            var senderDv = userRut.Substring(8);
            var rutCmopany = RutEmisor.Substring(0, 8);
            var rutCompnaydv = RutEmisor.Substring(9);
            nvc.Add("rutSender", rutSender);
            nvc.Add("dvSender", senderDv);
            nvc.Add("rutCompany", rutCmopany);
            nvc.Add("dvCompany", rutCompnaydv);

       
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" +
                                    boundary;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Headers.Add("POST", "/cgi_dte/UPL/DTEUpload HTTP/1.0");
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36";
            request.Accept = "image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/ms-excel,application/msword, */*" ;
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "TOKEN=" + token );
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "es-cl" );
            request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            request.Headers.Add("Referer", "http://empresaabc.cl/test.html");
            Stream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

            var boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" +
                                                                    boundary + "\r\n");
            var endBoundaryBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" +
                                                                        boundary + "--");


            string formdataTemplate = "\r\n--" + boundary +
                                        "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}";

           
            foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
            {
                string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, key, nvc[key]);
                byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
                memStream.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);
            }
           

            string headerTemplate = 
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1};\"\r\n" +
                "Content-Type: text/xml \r\n\r\n";

         
            memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
            var header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "file", "Enivo_DTE_test.xml");
            var headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);

            memStream.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[1024];
                var bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
          

            memStream.Write(endBoundaryBytes, 0, endBoundaryBytes.Length);
            request.ContentLength = memStream.Length;

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                memStream.Position = 0;
                byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
                memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
                memStream.Close();
                requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
            }

            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                Stream stream2 = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);
            var reuslt = reader2.ReadToEnd();
                return reuslt;
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()
```

By

```
System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes()
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is more interested:

```
public async Task<string> Enviar2(string pathfile, string rutCompany, string DvCompany)
{
using HttpClient httpClient = new();
using HttpRequestMessage request =
    new(HttpMethod.Post, "https://palena.sii.cl/cgi_dte/UPL/DTEUpload");
MultipartFormDataContent form =
    new()
    {
        { new StringContent($"{Rut!.Split('-')[0]!}"), "rutSender" },
        { new StringContent($"{Rut!.Split('-')[1]!}"), "dvSender" },
        { new StringContent(rutCompany), "rutCompany" },
        { new StringContent(DvCompany), "dvCompany" }
    };
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(pathfile))
{
    StreamContent streamContent = new(stream);
    streamContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(MediaTypeNames.Text.Xml);
    form.Add(streamContent, "archivo", Path.GetFileName(pathfile));
}

request.Content = form;
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
using StreamReader reader =
    new(
        await response
            .EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
            .Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false)
    );
return XDocument.Load(reader).ToString();
```

}